# Black sceen with nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 14.04 (NVIDIA GTX1050 ti notebook)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

PC SPEC:

1. MSI GE62 7RE-635JP
2. Intel Core i7-7700HQ Processor
3. NVIDIA GeForce GTX1050Ti/4GB GDDR5

When I installed nvidia driver downloaded from nvidia.com (381.22), I get black screen when I start Ubuntu.

Also, I've tried a lot way to install driver, for example [blacklist nouveau], [install with no opengl files option], [use apt-get to install driver], but those doesn't work for me.

How can I use graphic board(GTX1050 ti) on ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: I tried but It doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you installing 14.04 to a new laptop? Why are you installing drivers not from a repo or a PPA?

Comment: Because I need to use Ubuntu 14.04 for my work, and I also tried to installing drivers from repo and PPA but It has same problem.

Comment: @elemental_BOB - Pilot6 is telling your the right thing to install it from repo or PPA. The driver from nvidia may not work properly.

Comment: Try other version of the Nvidia driver like 375. I had similar issue with latest drivers and ubuntu. You can also try to install newest kernel like `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11/` and then Nvidia drivers. Also like others asked - why are You installed ubuntu 14 instead of the latest one ?

Comment: @Ashu I am sorry that I do not understand well.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I will try to install newest kernel thank you. So I want to use Robot Operating System in Ubuntu and my robot is Supported by Ubuntu 14.04 only, so I want to use laptop in 14.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried this - which is the one and only way of installing nvidia drivers on ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install dkms ppa-purge
sudo apt-get install nvidia-381
```

If still no luck I strongly suggest to try Ubuntu 16.04 and apply the same process of installing driver.

In all these cases secure boot MUST be disabled.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried to do that and I got a can't login problem so I will find another way to use GPU thank you.